# Coroutines. How to launch parallel coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I need to make 3 parallel request. And I need an exception for one request not to block or cancel the execution of another coroutine except for only one type of exception.
Here is my code:

```
 coroutineScope {
            awaitAll(
                async {
                    repository.firstRequest()
                },

                async {
                    repository.secondRequest()
                },

                async { repository.thirdRequest() },
            )
        }
```

But awaitAll fails immediately as soon as any of the deferreds fail. This is not what I expect.

Comment: use [`supervisorScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html) instead.